# Windows Mobile- Phone's camera application (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I want to create an application that once lunched, will start recording video and once the user press the SAVE button, the last recorded 5 seconds would be saved to an AVI file.

How should I do this?
I've played a little with the CameraCaptureDialog but I don't think that I can use it for my purposes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

U should use [SHCameraCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb160743.aspx) to launch camera capture dialog

Also check [SHCAMERACAPTURE Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb431794.aspx) for file types and etc

Also [SDK comes along with sample codes](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=6135) , try [Camera Capture Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158743.aspx)